# Unable to set get all params from google endpoint class

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I created a Model class in backend and then I clicked Generate Google Cloud Endpoint class. But when I am using it in Android, I am unable to get all fields from the Model class.

My Model class is this:

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetailsEntity {


@Id
private String userName;
private String password;

public UserDetailsEntity(String userName, String password) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}
public UserDetailsEntity() {
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

After creating Google Endpoint class from this in Studio I used below code to access it:

```
if (userDetailApi == null) {
            UserDetailsEntityApi.Builder builder = new UserDetailsEntityApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    .setRootUrl(Constants.URL);
            userDetailApi = builder.build();
        }
        try {
            userDetail = userDetailApi.get(mEmail);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But then userDetail.getUserName() method is available but userDetail.getPassword() is not available in app. Why? What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call userDetailApi.get(mEmail).execute(); to get the actual remote object you want.